# Cognos Report Studio 10.2.2 case statement sql logic

Tags: sql, cognos, cognos-10

I am trying to get this sql logic to work and the last part is where i do not have my logic correct.

I need to bring back readmits for providers that have listed as ID_1 & ID_2. If a person has a readmit within 30 days then they get a readmit_conf_30 number even if they went to another place. I need to have the original provider numbers and the other providers in the report if they have a readmit within 30 days of of each other.

I have tried many ways and am at a loss for how to word it. Group1 is for providers that i am looking for. Group2 is for other providers. Group3 unions them together and Group4 i try to assign them Y/N whether i want them on report. That is where i need help in the case logic.

Thanks for the help.

Code:

```
WITH Group1 AS 
(
    SELECT 
        A.MEMBER, B.SEX, B.DOB, B.LAST_NAME, B.FIRST_NAME,              
        A.PROVIDER_ID, C.PROVIDER_NAME, A.CONF_NUM, A.BEG_DT, A.END_DT, A.TOS_I_4, A.DIS_STAT, A.AMT_EQV,   A.AMT_PAY, A.AMT_REQ
        , A.READMIT_INDEX_30, A.READMIT_30, A.READMIT_CONF_30, '04/30/2014' as  DateCheck
        , '341425870018' AS ID_1
        , '341425870052' AS  ID_2
FROM CONFINEMENTS A 
LEFT JOIN MEMINFO B ON A.MEMBER = B.MEMBER 
LEFT JOIN PROVINFO C ON A.PROVIDER_ID = C.PROVIDER_ID
LEFT JOIN MAP_DATE_RANGE D ON D.IA_TIME = A.IA_TIME
WHERE 
    A.CUST_OPL_MED IN ('A$*', 'B$*', 'N$*', 'P$*', 'D$*', ' 'Unspecified$UNK')
    AND A.BEG_DT >= '05/01/2013' and A.beg_dt <'05/01/2014' 
    and A.PROVIDER_ID  Like '341425870%'  
    and (A.READMIT_30 = 1 OR A.READMIT_30 = 0)
    --AND A.DIS_STAT <> 20
),
GROUP2 AS (
    SELECT 
        A.MEMBER, B.SEX, B.DOB, B.LAST_NAME, B.FIRST_NAME, A.PROVIDER_ID,  C.PROVIDER_NAME
    , A.CONF_NUM, A.BEG_DT, A.END_DT, A.TOS_I_4, A.DIS_STAT, A.AMT_EQV,  A.AMT_PAY, A.AMT_REQ
    , A.READMIT_INDEX_30, A.READMIT_30, A.READMIT_CONF_30,  '04/30/2014' as  DateCheck
    , '341425870018' AS ID_1
    , '341425870052' AS  ID_2
FROM CONFINEMENTS A 
LEFT JOIN MEMINFO B ON A.MEMBER = B.MEMBER 
LEFT JOIN PROVINFO C ON A.PROVIDER_ID = C.PROVIDER_ID
LEFT JOIN MAP_DATE_RANGE D ON D.IA_TIME = A.IA_TIME
WHERE
    A.CUST_OPL_MED IN ('A$*', 'B$*', 'N$*', 'P$*', 'D$*', 'Unspecified$UNK')
    AND A.BEG_DT >= '05/01/2013' and A.beg_dt <'05/01/2014' 
    --and A.PROVIDER_ID  Like '341425870%'  
    and (A.READMIT_30 = 1 OR A.READMIT_30 = 0)
    --AND A.DIS_STAT <> 20
),
GROUP3 AS (
    Select *, DATEADD(dd, 30, datecheck) AS MaxdateAllowed from Group1
    union 
    select *, DATEADD(dd, 30, datecheck) AS MaxdateAllowed from GROUP2
),
    Group4 AS (
    select *
    , case when PROVIDER_ID <> ID_1 and readmit_conf_30 is not null THEN 'Y' 
        when PROVIDER_ID <> ID_2 and readmit_conf_30 is not null THEN 'Y' 
        when PROVIDER_ID = ID_1  and readmit_conf_30 is not null THEN 'Y'
        when PROVIDER_ID = ID_2  and readmit_conf_30 is not null THEN 'Y'
        when PROVIDER_ID = ID_1 THEN 'Y'
        when PROVIDER_ID =  ID_2 THEN 'Y'
        when PROVIDER_ID <> ID_1 THEN 'N'
        when PROVIDER_ID <> ID_2 THEN 'N'
        ELSE 'B'
    END AS GoodRecord
    FROM Group3
    where maxdateallowed > beg_dt and READMIT_INDEX_30 = 1 
    --and (READMIT_30 = 1 OR READMIT_30 = 0)
)
SELECT * FROM Group4 
WHERE GoodRecord = 'Y'
order by conf_num
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. 
SQL Code Below :-

```
WITH Group1 AS (
        SELECT A.MEMBER, B.SEX, B.DOB, B.LAST_NAME, B.FIRST_NAME, A.PROVIDER_ID,    C.PROVIDER_NAME
        , A.CONF_NUM, A.BEG_DT, A.END_DT, A.TOS_I_4, A.DIS_STAT, A.AMT_EQV,        A.AMT_PAY, A.AMT_REQ
        , A.READMIT_INDEX_30, A.READMIT_30, A.READMIT_CONF_30
        FROM CONFINEMENTS A 
        LEFT JOIN MEMINFO B ON A.MEMBER = B.MEMBER 
        LEFT JOIN PROVINFO C ON A.PROVIDER_ID = C.PROVIDER_ID
        LEFT JOIN MAP_DATE_RANGE D ON D.IA_TIME = A.IA_TIME
        WHERE A.CUST_OPL_MED IN ('A$*', 'B$*', 'N$*', 'P$*', 'D$*', 'Unspecified$UNK')
        AND A.BEG_DT >= '05/01/2013' and A.beg_dt <'05/01/2014' 
        and A.PROVIDER_ID  Like '341425870%'  
        and (A.READMIT_30 = 1 OR A.READMIT_30 = 0)
),
GROUP2 AS (
       SELECT AA.MEMBER, AA.READMIT_CONF_30
       FROM Group1 AA
       WHERE AA.READMIT_CONF_30 > 0
),
Group3 AS (
       Select AA.MEMBER, A.READMIT_CONF_30, A.CONF_NUM
       ,B.SEX, B.DOB, B.LAST_NAME, B.FIRST_NAME, A.PROVIDER_ID, C.PROVIDER_NAME
       , A.BEG_DT, A.END_DT, A.TOS_I_4, A.DIS_STAT, A.AMT_EQV, A.AMT_PAY, A.AMT_REQ
       , A.READMIT_30, A.READMIT_INDEX_30
       FROM GROUP2 AA
       LEFT JOIN CONFINEMENTS A ON A.MEMBER = AA.MEMBER AND AA.READMIT_CONF_30 = A.CONF_NUM
       LEFT JOIN MEMINFO B ON A.MEMBER = B.MEMBER 
       LEFT JOIN PROVINFO C ON A.PROVIDER_ID = C.PROVIDER_ID
       LEFT JOIN MAP_DATE_RANGE D ON D.IA_TIME = A.IA_TIME
       WHERE A.CUST_OPL_MED IN ('A$*', 'B$*', 'N$*', 'P$*', 'D$*',  'Unspecified$UNK')

       and (A.READMIT_30 = 1 OR A.READMIT_30 = 0)
)
      select 
      MEMBER, READMIT_CONF_30
      ,SEX, DOB, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, PROVIDER_ID, PROVIDER_NAME
      , CONF_NUM, BEG_DT, END_DT, TOS_I_4, DIS_STAT, AMT_EQV, AMT_PAY, AMT_REQ
      , READMIT_30, READMIT_INDEX_30
      from group1
      union 
      select 
      MEMBER, READMIT_CONF_30
     ,SEX, DOB, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, PROVIDER_ID, PROVIDER_NAME
     , CONF_NUM, BEG_DT, END_DT, TOS_I_4, DIS_STAT, AMT_EQV, AMT_PAY, AMT_REQ
     , READMIT_30, READMIT_INDEX_30
     from Group3
     order by conf_num
```